# Pandas: How to filter out continuous cell values who are continuously increasing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

For example, in the following sample, I would like to find out the rows filtered by the following filters:

*(the solution should be easy to switch between filter 1 and 2.)*

Filters:

1. Z > Y > X .... > C > B > A
2. H < I < J < K < N

df = df[***here***] ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(
    0, 100, size=(100, 26)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))

print(df)


     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
0   98  35  55  27  91  91  15  76  83  49  32  20   0  10  21  59  22  85  62  48  69  98  47  74  93  31
1   89  78  70  98  26  45   8  35  60  27  29  93  56  75  98  19  63  32  43  11  84  65  71  33  93   2
2   97  18  19  18  29  74  65  44  18  37  30  12  18  82  60   4  24  80  59  66   0  96  93  39  36  95
3   20  83  35  16  57  31   7   3  74  81  33  28  41  48  94  85  78  15  53  24  45  75  20  35  24   9
4   56  73  13  89  42  50  67   3  61  71  34  98  45  64  22  10  44  44  92  86   4  14  45  98  16  91
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
95   0  56  71  66  43  11  75  25  73  66  62  62  15  81  61  24   0   3  50  18  25  78  14   9   4  37
96   4  23   8  57  14  12  29  49  67  48  97  74   9  75  11  18  24  77  50  90  59  38  62  12  77  16
97  27  26  74  71  21  14  84  27  99  59  15  34  48  44   3  89  46  11  63  58  80  14  93  20  36  14
98  76  64   7  89  74  32  17  17  34  25  10  99  67  21  89  28  78  19  81  74  68  52  90  59  81  19
99  88  69  16  73  65  70  68  68  41  72  46  32  82  57   1  55  31  28  59  93  89  85  99  31   0  84
```

Is there a smart way of filtering?

I know there we can write code like:

```
df = df[ (df['Z'] > df['Y']) & (df['Y'] > df['X']) & ... & (df['B'] > df['A'])]
```

but what if there are hundreds columns then

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "mask":

```
mask1 = (df["Z"] > df["Y"]) & (df["Y"] > df["X"]) & (df["X"] > df["C"])
print (mask1)


mask2 = (df["H"] < df["I"]) & (df["I"] < df["J"]) & (df["J"] > df["K"])
print (mask2)
```

Comment: Yes, this works, what if there are 100 columns to compare then?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check all columns then you can use `is_monotonic_increasing`

```
In [3]: df.apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic, axis =1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[3]: 
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
      ...  
95    False
96    False
97    False
98    False
99    False
Length: 100, dtype: bool

In [4]: mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic, axis =1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [5]: df[mask]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[5]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
Index: []
```

If you have to check for selective columns with some random order , i suggest using `query` . you can just swap out the string with any other combination without any performance impact.

```
In [6]: df.query('H < I < J < K < N')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: 
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q  R   S   T  U   V   W   X   Y   Z
87  3  66  96  26  56  27  59  33  46  48  52  95  58  73  23  81  14  6  31  54  1  74  80  43  99  30
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method below you only need to know the index of the columns to be compared:

```
#filter 1

rows_filtered = []
columns = range(26)


for row in df.index:
    line = df.iloc[row].to_numpy()[columns]
    if sorted(range(len(line)), key=lambda k: line[k]) == list(range(26)):
        print(line)
        rows_filtered.append(row)

if len(rows_filtered) == 0:
    print('there are no rows that pass the filter')
        
df_filtered = df.loc[rows_filtered]
df_filtered

#filter 2

rows_filtered = []
columns = [7,8,9,10,13]

for row in df.index:
    line = df.iloc[row].to_numpy()[columns]
    if sorted(range(len(line)), key=lambda k: line[k]) == list(range(5)):
        print(line)
        rows_filtered.append(row)
        
if len(rows_filtered) == 0:
    print('there are no rows that pass the filter')
        
df_filtered = df.loc[rows_filtered]
df_filtered
```

Here an example that returns a non-empty data frame:

```
rows_filtered = []
columns = [0,1,2]

for row in df.index:
    line = df.iloc[row].to_numpy()[columns]
    if sorted(range(len(line)), key=lambda k: line[k]) == list(range(3)):
        print(line)
        rows_filtered.append(row)
        
if len(rows_filtered) == 0:
    print('there are no rows that pass the filter')

df_filtered = df.loc[rows_filtered]
df_filtered
```